# MySQL query select in select

Tags: mysql

```
Country Value Type
AU        152 IN
AU         56 OUT
IN         85 IN
CA         74 OUT
CA         98 IN
IN         89 IN
US        124 IN
UK        856 OUT
IN         35 OUT
AU         26 IN
PS         24 OUT
CN        869 OUT
```

i need a query that groups the country and prints the sum of IN and OUT fields separately like
Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Don't you think that it is inappropriate to post 2 pictures and write *"do the work for me"*? You should: 1) Prepare http://sqlfiddle.com demo with sample data 2) Show what have you tried so far? It is really easy query.

Comment: Have you tried something? Please also add if it is assured there always be an IN and an OUT, and if it's not what is expected if so..

Comment: + your example doesn't match your description. For example the sum of IN for AU is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

it will give you count of all indivisual country

```
SELECT country, 
SUM(case when type = 'IN' then 1 END) AS IN,
SUM(case when type = 'OUT' then 1 END) AS OUT 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY country
```

it will give you sum of all indivisual country's value

```
SELECT country, 
SUM(case when type = 'IN' then value END) AS IN,
SUM(case when type = 'OUT' then value END) AS OUT 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY country
```